# Different same but same result with zlib

Tags: java, base64, zip, zlib

I have duplicate check who didn't work because my zlib hash are different for a same file.

I got a encrypted data (XML file) with AES from my client.
I decrypted the data (with Cipher) and got a byte array of the data zipped and base64 encoded.

I decode base64, unzlib and got my XML file.

If I do it again, I got a different base64 out of the Cipher. I decode it, unzlib and got exactly the same XML as below.

With this problem my duplicate check didnt work because base64 value is different and I didn't understand why.

My base64 value is around 3000 char and only the 10-15 last char are differents.

Actually this software is in PHP and all is good with it. On the new server in JAVA we got this error.

So the client data are correct, JAVA do something I can't explain.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably the date/time stamps in the zip file.  You're updating them and the old code isn't.  Check the date/times of the files involved and make sure they aren't changing.

Comment: But it's not a zip file it's a byte array of the xml compressed, I didnt see any timestamp at the end then, I can remove these information and get only the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather difficult to parse, but I think what you're saying is that if you decompress something compressed by PHP and then recompress it with Java, you get different compressed data. When you decompress that data, you get exactly the original uncompressed data.

If that is correct, *then there is no problem*. There is no assurance that a different compressor will produce the same result, or even the same compressor since you can have different settings, or even the same compressor with the same settings, since you could be using a different version. "I decode it, unzlib and got exactly the same XML as below.", means that all the compressors and decompressors are doing what they are supposed to do. There is no assurance that decompression followed by compression will ever produce exactly the same result. The only assurance of a lossless compressor is that compression followed by decompression will produce exactly the same result.

You are creating a problem for yourself with "I have duplicate check". Checking the compressed data does not check for duplicated uncompressed data. If you want to look for duplicates, or if you want to check the integrity of your compression, transmission, and decompression process, then you need to do both using the *uncompressed* data, not the compressed data.